# C++ calculator that reads from left to right and contains +,-,/,*

Tags: c++, calculator

I need to make a c++ program that runs a single line of input and reads it from left to right. At the end of the input the user adds # to signal the input is done. I got the calculator to work, however if the user only inputs # and hits enter the program needs to be able to throw an error code. Otherwise we can assume the user inputs things correctly. Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int var1, var2, total;
    char operation;
    cout << "Enter an equation: ";
    cin >> var1;
    /*if (var1 == 0)
    {
        cout << "error";// cant pass in info via char because var1 is
        return 1;       // in the way and using var == 0 technique is
        *               // cheating because then you can't do 0#
    */ 
    else
    {
        do
        {
            cin >> operation;
            if (operation == '#')
            {
                cout << var1;
            }
            else
            {
                cin >> var2;
            }
            if(operation == '+')
            total = var1 + var2;
            else if(operation == '-')
            total = var1 - var2;
            else if(operation == '/')
            total = var1 / var2;
            else if(operation == '*')
            total = var1 * var2;
            var1 = total;
        }while (operation != '#');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I know I need to run cin var 1 before I do anything else. Is there anyway for me to grab the first character of an input without changing it? I really don't know what else to do. If anything needs ti be cleared up just ask.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use reverse polish notation with shunt yard algorithm. you can solve this mathematical expression calculation easily with it. if you need i can provide source. but its written in java

I have uploaded my source to my drive. follow this link https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxH1JbPpi3XKNWxXeW91VEFGY1E&usp=sharing

Comment: I would appreciate that, I can convert it.

Answer (score 1):

an easier way to do that is by validating the input of the user . so if you only accept " +-*/" then I would suggest that you create a check function that returns error for example :

```
bool check(char x)
{
if (x == '+' || x == '-' || x == '*' || x == '/');
else return false;
}

int main()
{
 float total;
 int var1, var2;
 char operation;

//input
do
{
    cout << "Enter an equation: ";
    cin >> var1>> operation>>var2;
    if (check(operation) == false)
        cout << "Error! Unidentified operation symbol..." << endl;
} while (check(operation) == false);


//Process
if (operation == '+')
    total = var1 + var2;
else if (operation == '-')
    total = var1 - var2;
else if (operation == '/')
    total = var1 / var2;
else if (operation == '*')
    total = var1 * var2;

//output
cout << total << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

hope this helps :)